# What is the "miniboss" music that plays in Kingdom Hearts: Birth By Sleep in multiple worlds?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep, game-music-identification

There is a specific track that plays during certain instances in Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep. It is not the 'regular' boss theme (Unforgettable); it is also not specific to any world, because I have at least two examples of where this music plays:

- As Aqua, shortly after you meet Prince Phillip, where you are first tasked with taking out Maleficent's goons;
- As Aqua, when you fight alongside Mickey against Unversed in Radiant Garden ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOWrziA_az8))

I can't find an example right now, but I'm pretty sure it isn't specific to Aqua either. Can anyone tell me which track this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song in the video you linked is titled as [Rowdy Rumble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj8a6iKxeJ4).

This is certainly not an Aqua only track. This song appears in a few mini-boss battles at Terra & Ventus, and is a track in Kingdom Hearts 2 as well.